# throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i call javascript function while onclick in anchor tag throws this error please see the code below.

```
<a href="#" onclick='DoNavi(<%=url%>);'>
</a>

<script>
    <preserve>
    <![CDATA[
       function DoNavi(theURL)
       {
           alert("function");                              
       }          
    ]]>
    </preserve>
</script>
```

Comment: is `<preserver>` a javascript tag? If not; There's your problem. :) It's pretty much a typo in your Javascript. But since I can't find a mistake in the script it must be the `<preserve>` tag.

Comment: A few obvious things, what's with the `preserve` tags? Also, you need to quote the string around the url, it will end up being `DoNavi(http://foo)` when you want it to be `DoNavi("http://foo")`

Comment: <a href="#" onclick='DoNavi("<%=url%>");'>

Comment: thanks every one solved using this<a href="#" onclick='DoNavi("<%=url%>");'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoNavi(<%=url%>);` must be between quotes because the url is a string:

`DoNavi('<%=url%>');`